# Firefox Mobile not running Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, testing, mobile

I am trying to run my local website Firefox mobile emulator. I am able to see the welcome page, but I am not able to enter into the website as it invloves running of some JS. Can any of you tell me how to enable it?

Thanks in advance,

Yamini

Answer (score 0):

Run Fennec.exe.  On the start page, drag part of the white background to the left, you will see a gear icon.  Click it.  Click 'Enable Javascript' under the Content heading.